# ios jailbreak: command cycrypt not found

Tags: ios

I have jail-broken my iPhone with Cydia store. In cydia store I have checked and I see `cycrypt` has installed.

But when I ssh to my iPhone and try to run command `cycrypt` I receive the following error, indicating cycrypt is not installed:

```
-sh: cycrypt: command not found
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you're trying to use is `cycript`, not `cycrypt`. Notice the **i** instead of your second **y**. That's why your ssh session fails executing it.